# I am looking for a written generic DAO, Base Entity Manager... for Neo4j

Tags: jpa, generics, neo4j, dao

Hope you are doing well.
I am new in Graph DB "Neo4j" and I am looking for Neo4j JPA generic DAO as I used for MySql DB. Is there any written generic DAO, Base Entity Manager...  for GraphAPI for Neo4j ???

Thanks advance.

Comment: "Graph API" is a totally different thing to the JPA API. The JPA API is designed TOTALLY for RDBMS, which Neo4j is not. Yes, there are Neo4j JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus JPA), but the JPA API is not ideally suited to that task.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please give me any suggestion or any link that give me a good start with Graph API "Neo4j".  Thanks advance

Comment: How about the "Neo4j docs" ?!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at :

- **neo4j-ogm** : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/
- **spring-data-neo4j** : https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/